# How to merge 2 messages in logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

here is my problem. I am using Logic Apps, and I am trying to create a message using a transform or any other idea from 2 incoming messages. I have been working with biztalk all my life and is so easy. It's called multipart message.

In example: Ingoing Message "A"   +  Ingoing Message "B" = Message "A" enriched or message "C".

I have been trying to use the compose. The result of the compose will be incoming of a xslt ( that is the idea). When I am trying to use the compose I can transform message "A" into json and message "B" is json based but for an unknown reason it can't be merge to new structure inside the compose.

If anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible today with compose - and we are also adding a new feature this month to allow you to inject a JSON property in an object. However i imagine something like this would work with compose. Let me know:

```
{ “A”: “@json(body(‘A’))”,
   “B”: “@json(body(‘B’))”
```

}